# Linq pass null to Where clause

Tags: linq

I have method which accept expression for Linq Where clause. Sometimes I would like to ignore Where clause and do not use it.

I have tried to pass null to the method like this

```
GetUsersView(null)
```

but got exception. How correctly do this?

```
 private IQueryable<UserView> GetUsersView(Expression<Func<User, bool>> expression)
        {            
            return _userRepository.GetAll().
                                   Where(expression).
                                   Select(p => new UserView
                                   {
                                       Id = p.Id,
                                       Active = p.Orders.Any(c => c.Active && (c.TransactionType == TransactionType.Order || c.TransactionType == TransactionType.Subscription)),
                                       DateStamp = p.DateStamp,
                                       Email = p.Email,
                                       FirstName = p.FirstName,
                                       LastName = p.LastName,
                                       Message = p.Message,
                                       UsersManager = p.Orders.Select(o => o.Product).Any(w => w.UsersManager && w.Active)
                                   });
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you check your expression for null? If its null, return _userRepository.GetAll(). Otherwise return that what you already have.

Comment: Did you try `GetUsersView(true)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing nulls to methods is a horrible idea. Passing `u => true` is not very readable either. Create two methods instead - one which has parameter, and other, which don't have. Also I see your method have two responsibilities - it filters users, and converts them to UserViews. I think filtering users by predicate should occur in repository.

You can also create extension method `IQueryable<UserView> ToViews(this IQueryable<User> source)`.

```
public static IQueryable<UserView> ToViews(this IQueryable<User> source)
{
    return source.Select(u => new UserView
         {
            Id = u.Id,
            Active = u.Orders.Any(o => o.Active && 
                            (o.TransactionType == TransactionType.Order ||
                             o.TransactionType == TransactionType.Subscription)),
            DateStamp = u.DateStamp,
            Email = u.Email,
            FirstName = u.FirstName,
            LastName = u.LastName,
            Message = u.Message,
            UsersManager = u.Orders.Select(o => o.Product)
                                   .Any(p => p.UsersManager && p.Active)
         });     
}
```

In this case code will look like:

```
private IQueryable<UserView> GetUserViews()
{
    return _userRepository.GetAll().ToViews();
}

private IQueryable<UserView> GetUserViews(Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate)
{
    // move filtering to repository      
    return _userRepository.GetAll(predicate).ToViews();        
}
```

Comment: Is it good idea to have method in repository with Predicate parameter? Or should I create separated repository method for every filter condition like _userRepository.GetAll(byId), _userRepository.GetAll(byEmail) and etc.

Comment: @Tomas I usually create specific repositories, which inherited from generic repository. Those specific repositories also implement interfaces like `IUserRepository` which have methods specific to users (like `FindByEmail`). Another solution is using specifications and generic repository, which accepts different specifications.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
GetUsersView(u=>true);
```

or if you would prefer not to type the expression all the time, you can create an overloaded function that provides a default expression.

```
IQueryable<UserView> GetUsersView()
{
   return GetUsersView(u=>true);
}
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that frameworks like entityframework actually translate u=>true into SQL, ... kind of dirties/complicates the query as can be seen in the profiler